# Angularjs socket.on event not working when socket connection changed in factory

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, factory, rootscope

I am having a factory for socket.io, If the user not loggedin then I am having

```
var socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL);
```

When the user logs into the site, then I am changing the socket value.

```
socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, {forceNew: true});
```

In my controller I have

```
socket.on('notification', function(data){console.log(data);})
```

This socket.on('notification') is not working after changing the socket variable in the factory.

My factory

```
app.factory('socket', function($rootScope){
     var socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL);
     return {
      reconnect:function(){
          console.log("reconnect");
          socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, {forceNew: true});
       },
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
         socket.on(eventName, function () {
             var args = arguments;
             $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
             });
         });
    }
});
```

My controllers

```
 app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, socket){
      $scope.login = function(){
            // .............
            socket.reconnect();
      }
 });


 app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, socket){
      socket.on('notification', function(data){ // this is not working 
          console.log(data);                  //after calling socket.reconnect();
      })
 });
```

Comment: `myCtrl2` function is only called initially and binds to the original socket which is destroyed when you reconnect.

Comment: Got that. But How to make the new socket to listen for events? I am having many listeners for socket.

Comment: here's a working example of a socket.io factory Groupon made for an open source project https://github.com/groupon/greenscreen/blob/master/public/js/gscreen.js#L81

Comment: Actually I think it helps far more than you realize.  When you're reinitializing socket on the reconnect, you're starting over with a whole new socket object.  Any previous socket.on events will be tied to the previous socket object.

Comment: @theaccordance Is it possible to add all the events tied to the previous socket object to new socket object?

Comment: I haven't done it myself before so purely speculation but I believe so.  The factory I sent you holds the events in an object, if I were in your situation I'd use that object to re-instantiate the events on reconnect.

Also, what I would look into first is whether the way you're addressing a reconnect is optimal or not. Might be a far easier way to go about this.